# Python 'exifread' module returns error when going thourg not picture e.g. .mp3

Tags: python, error-handling, exif, try-except

I'm building a Python program to sort pictures by "EXIF DateTimeOriginal" tag using the `exifread` module. There is an error when not picture file (e.g. .mp3 file) is processed by `exifread.process_file(item)`. I would like Python to ignore files without EXIF tags so I use `try, except` statement but it still returns the error `File format not recognized` which terminates the program.

I added `tags["EXIF DateTimeOriginal"] == True` which stopped program termination but the error is still printed.

Has anyone idea how to make `exifread` module to ignore files which are not pictures?

```
    import exifread

item = "D:\TEMP\Vesna.mp3"
    
with open(item, 'rb') as file:
    try:
        tags = exifread.process_file(file, stop_tag="EXIF DateTimeOriginal")
        tags["EXIF DateTimeOriginal"] == True
    except:
        print("No tag")
    else:
        taken = tags["EXIF DateTimeOriginal"]
        print(tags["EXIF DateTimeOriginal"])


**returns**
File format not recognized.
No tag
```

I could sort out not picture files before fetching them to `exifread` commands but I have the impression that it would take more time and also some images could still not possess the required tag.

Comment: `process_file` logs the error and returns `{}` instead of raising en exception. That's why you see "File format not recognized". But I can't explain "No tag". You ran this exact code?

Comment: `except:` catches all exceptions which runs the risk of catching more programming errors than you expect. By simply suppressing it, rather than logging the error and its traceback (at least in a settable debug mode), you loose useful information for debug.

Comment: @tdelaney "No tag" message shows that the program went through 'except:' and 'print' statements which theoretically should guarantee a lack of errors raised.

Comment: I found `process_file` at https://github.com/ianare/exif-py/blob/develop/exifread/__init__.py. It appears to log the exception (that's why you see it printed) and return `{}` - no exception. You could setup [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) yourself to suppress that message. If this is the case, where did the exception come from? Not the other line of your code. That's why I asked. So, is this the exact code that produced the output?

Comment: Oh wait, I'm blind. `tags["EXIF DateTimeOriginal"] == True` - didn't notice the `==` equality test. You may have wanted the `=` assignment operator.

Comment: Thank you for your help @tdalaney. Yes, that is the exact code that generates these errors or warnings. The only difference with the outcome when replacing `==` with `=` is that "File format not recognised." message displays before or after "No tag" message, which makes the whole thing even more confusing because I'm not able to localise the source of the "File format not recognised." message. Also, debugging in PyCharm doesn't help at all. I don't know how to suppress logging?

Answer (score 1):

From the [source](https://github.com/ianare/exif-py/blob/develop/exifread/__init__.py), `process_file` catches file type errors, logs a warning message and returns an empty `dict`.  You could test for the empty `dict` or, since you are also concerned about an entry in that `dict`, use a `get` with a default value for test. And you can change what happens to a logging event with the [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) module.

```
import exifread
import logging

item = "D:\TEMP\Vesna.mp3"

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR)

with open(item, 'rb') as file:
    tags = exifread.process_file(file, stop_tag="EXIF DateTimeOriginal")
if tags.get("EXIF DateTimeOriginal", True):
    taken = tags["EXIF DateTimeOriginal"]
    print(tags["EXIF DateTimeOriginal"])
else:
    print("No tag")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution @tdelaney still raised an Error so I tweaked it slightly and here is the result. Thanks for the introduction to the `logging` module :)

```
import exifread
import logging

item = "D:\TEMP\\20160130_215245.jpg"

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR)

try:
    file = open(item, 'rb')
    tags = exifread.process_file(file, stop_tag="EXIF DateTimeOriginal")
    taken = tags["EXIF DateTimeOriginal"]
except:
    print("No tag")
else:
    print(tags["EXIF DateTimeOriginal"])
```